# Network Permissions, Traversing Folders, Command Line

Tags: networking, command-line, windows-7, command-line-arguments, windows-server-2008-r2

I am trying to delete a text file from my command line in a directory that exists in a Failover cluster in a Windows 2008 R2 server, to which I am connected over my corporate network.

I have all appropriate rights granted to the particular folder, and am able to delete the text file manually in explorer.

However if I try to execute the command

```
del "\\NETWORKPATH\filename.txt"
```

I get the error:

```
Access is denied.
```

I believe this is because the command line execution has trouble traversing the folder structure of the target directory without running into permission rights (as I don't have, and cannot have, rights to all of the higher level folders).

**As a workaround, is there a way alter my command line code to mimic the way that I access the directory manually through explorer?**

Thanks kindly, and let me know if I can clarify anything as I am a bit out of my depth.

Comment: doesn't windows use the '\' char for path separator? Good luck.

Comment: thanks.  unfortunately, the command is well-formed from that angle.  edits reflected.

Comment: not really a programming question, which is the focus here on S.O. Please click the flag link at bottom and request to have this moved to SuperUser.com. Can you CD to \\NEWORKPATH and then `del filename.txt`? Also, that this is a failover cluster should be highlighted. Windows does some screwy things in the name of saving your from yourself. Good luck.